# TinyMT example Initialisation, Usage

Tags: c, random

I'm having a problem with my C code when using [TinyMT](https://github.com/MersenneTwister-Lab/TinyMT).
I am wanting an explanation on how the functions work and want they are wanting for their parameters.

My linter is throwing errors already :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tinymt64.h"

int main(void){
  int r;
  tinymt64_init(r,100)
  tinymt64_generate_uint64(r);
  return 0;
}
```

[TinyMT](https://github.com/MersenneTwister-Lab/TinyMT) library is being used to randomly generate numbers, there is no documentation on how to use this, I would love if someone could give me a directions on how to use this fantastic tool!

Thank you in advance

Comment: [The implementation contains the documentation as comments](https://github.com/MersenneTwister-Lab/TinyMT/blob/master/tinymt/tinymt64.c).

Comment: Could you elaborate, I don't know what I need to put in the random parameter and I can't find in the comments what you're suppose to put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the comments in the [source code](https://github.com/MersenneTwister-Lab/TinyMT/blob/master/tinymt/tinymt64.c):

```
/**
 * This function initializes the internal state array with a 64-bit
 * unsigned integer seed.
 * @param random tinymt state vector.
 * @param seed a 64-bit unsigned integer used as a seed.
 */
void tinymt64_init(tinymt64_t * random, uint64_t seed)
```

The corresponding [header file](https://github.com/MersenneTwister-Lab/TinyMT/blob/master/tinymt/tinymt64.h) also says:

```
/**
 * This function outputs 64-bit unsigned integer from internal state.
 * @param random tinymt internal status
 * @return 64-bit unsigned integer r (0 <= r < 2^64)
 */
inline static uint64_t tinymt64_generate_uint64(tinymt64_t * random)
```

The latter is in the header file (and `inline static`), because it is very simple, and the original author wanted to make it clear to C compilers that the function can be inlined (and thus the extra "cost" of a function call should be avoided).

There is no function to get a random seed (an unsigned 64-bit integer), so either the [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) will generate the same sequence of random numbers, or we'll need to somehow generate a suitable seed ourselves.

Let's implement the above comments into an example program. Let's use a fixed seed, `1`, for simplicity.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tinymt64.h"

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t    seed = UINT64_C(1);
    uint64_t    value;
    tinymt64_t  prng;

    tinymt64_init(&prng, seed);

    value = tinymt64_generate_uint64(&prng);

    printf("The first value using seed %" PRIu64 " is %" PRIu64 ".\n",
           seed, value);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because I use GCC, I saved the above as `example.c`, put the two files in the same directory, and compiled them all using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -c tinymt64.c
gcc -Wall -O2 -c example.c
gcc -Wall -O2 example.o tinymt64.o -o example
```

so I can run it using

```
./example
```

The code is standard C, and should compile on all systems where the TinyMT64 compiles, including on Windows.

Let's look at the code.

First, `tinymt64_init()` takes a pointer to a `tinymt64_t`, and an `uint64_t` seed. The first is used as the state of the generator, and the second as the seed value (used to initialize the state). Because the state is a small structure (`struct TINYMT64_T`, later typedef'd to `tinymt64_t` in the header file), and has no flexible array member, we can just declare the state as a normal variable, `tinymt64_t prng;`. The pointer to the state is then `&prng`. The function returns nothing.

Second, `tinymt64_generate_uint64()` takes only a pointer to the generator state, and returns the pseudorandom number as an `uint64_t`.

Finally, the `UINT64_C()` macro is defined in `inttypes.h` (or `stdint.h`), and allows you to define unsigned 64-bit integers from `0` to `18446744073709551615`, inclusive, without guessing which type suffix (none, `UL`, or possibly `ULL`) you might need on that particular compiler. (If the constant is smaller than 2<sup>31</sup> = `2147483648`, you don't need the macro, but having it does no harm.)

The `PRIu64` macro is defined in `inttypes.h`, and defines the conversion pattern (except for the leading `%` and optional size fields) `printf()` family of functions needs to print an `uint64_t` properly.

If you wanted to read the seed from e.g. the command line, you can use e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t    seed = UINT64_C(1);
    uint64_t    value;
    tinymt64_t  prng;
    char        dummy;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], "%" SCNu64 " %c", &seed, &dummy) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not an unsigned 64-bit integer.\n", argv[1]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

which uses the first command-line argument, if one is specified, and the default constant seed (`1`) otherwise.

Comment: Small question I'm getting this error when trying to compile.'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_tinymt64_init", referenced from:'

Comment: @AngusForrest: Trying to compile what? The above program using the commands I showed? If not, then you'll need to be more specific, because my current medication suppresses my long-range telepathic skills.

Comment: it's the example above, sorry for not saying. thanks again.

Comment: Oh, it was just a compiling error, I found it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AngusForrest: Good; I was quite scratching my head as to how that could happen. (If you use GCC, the parameter order is significant.)